# Replace a statement with another one with shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I have one statement needed to be substituted. The original format is like:

```
f.STRING.focus();
```

Where the `STRING` is the combination of `[:alpha:]` and `[:digit:]` (regular expression). 
My purpose is to change it to

```
highlight("STRING");
```

For instance:

```
f.abCDef12345.focus()    --->     highlight("abCDef12345");
f.ip2.focus()            --->     highlight("ip2");
```

I can easily use `sed` to replace the statement for hundreds of html files. However, I don't know how to  get the `STRING` in shell script.

Procedures can be described as follow:

```
For each html:
    For the STRING which matches the pattern:
        1. Assign it to a parameter.
        2. Insert that STRING to highlight("STRING");
        3. Replace the old one "f.STRING.focus();" to "highlight("STRING");"
```

But I don't know how to write them in shell script... Any hint is appreciated.

Updated:

1. Please describe your script clearly. Thank you too much!
2. SORRY FOR THE MISTAKE!  `STRING` IS THE COMBINATION OF and `[:alpha:]` and `[:digit:]`. So the example mentioned here `f.ip2.focus()` can make sense.

Comment: Can't you just use sed with regexp on multiple files? I'm not sure if I got the idea correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    sed 's/f\.\([0-9a-zA-Z]*\)\.focus()/highlight("\1")/g' $line
done < <(find . -type f  -name '*.html')
```

When you're happy with the output change the sed-command to `sed -i.bak` instead to do inline-replace.

Explanation:

1. The `find` command searches recursively from the current folder and down for all files named `.html`
2. a bash while-read loop read one line at a time of the output from the find-command
3. `sed` is then  used for searching for the desired pattern and the pattern `\(...\)` is called a caption-group that stores the matching text in a variable that can accessed using `\1` which is called a back-reference.

The *proper* way to read and operate on each line of a file in bash is to use

```
while read line
do
    echo $line
done < file
```

In our case, we don't have a file, instead we'd like to operate on each line of the output of a command, enter [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) `<(...)` You can of course redirect the find-command to a file using redirection `find ... > file` and then operate on that.

**Update**:

As pointed out by @tripleee the while-loop can be dropped completely:

```
sed -i.bak 's/f\.\([0-9a-zA-Z]*\)\.focus()/highlight("\1")/g' $(find . -type f  -name '*.html')
```

The `sed '...' $(find...)` construct executes the part in `$()` in a subshell, delivering all the matching files as parameters to the sed-command as seen below

```
sed '...' ./c/file.html ./a/file.html ./b/file.html ./d/file.html
```

If you have a lot of html-files, the shell might throw an error due to too long command-line; if that is the case `xargs` is your friend (man xargs).

..or (Linux is full of [TMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)), let `find` execute the sed-part for all matching files (one at a time), in that way you don't risk the problem of getting a too long command line:

```
find . -type f  -name '*.html' -exec sed 's/f\.\([0-9a-zA-Z]*\)\.focus()/highlight("\1")/g' {} \;
```

Comment: I don't know why should I add `parentheses` around `[:alpha:]` and what does `("\1")` exactly mean?
Also, sorry I can't figure out the last statement `done < <(find . -type f  -name '*.html')`. Please explain and add some references.

Comment: Error msg: `redirection unexpected` in the last line.

Comment: It might be that your bash is actually a symlink to dash. Dash do not support process substitution. Check with `ls -l /bin/bash` or are you using `/bin/sh` as your shebang?

Comment: Well...  The spaces between done and second < in `done < <(find . -type f  -name '*.html')` cause the error: redirection unexpected. If I delete one, I got `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`. Btw,why should I have to pass the command to `done`?

Comment: you don't pass anything to `done`. done terminates the while-loop.

Comment: The `while` loop is completely superfluous. You can `sed '...' $(find ...)` or `find ... -exec sed '...' \;`

Comment: @Fredrik Pihl  How can I check my shebang? I only know the spaces between done and the second `<` in `done < <(find . -type f -name '*.html')` cause the error: redirection unexpected.

Comment: @tripleee  You should add the option `-i`.  `sed -i '...' $(find ...)`
Can you explain the syntax you used?

Comment: @FredrikPihl  I hope you can update your answer and you can get the point.

Comment: updated and @tripleee you are right (as always) I used the while-loop for readability, thought that was easier to understand...

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i 's/f\.\([a-zA-Z0-9]\+\)\.focus()/highlight("\1")/g' file_to_process
```

1. `f\.` matches `f.`
2. `\([a-zA-Z0-9]\+\)` matches one or more alphanumeric characters and stores matched `STRING` in variable `1`
3. `\.focus()` matches `.focus()`
4. `highlight("\1")` replaces whole matched pattern with given text and value of variable `1` -> `higlight("STRING")`

Comment: Doesn't match the provided test-string `abCDef12345`

Comment: Maybe because of that `:alpha:` is `a-z A-Z` only?

Comment: There is clearly stated `STRING is the combination of [:alpha:]` in question.

Comment: Sorry for that. Updated~

Answer (score 0):

`sed -i 's/b.\(STRING\).focus()/highlight("\1")/g' file` will do the trick

`#echo "b.STRING.focus()"| sed 's/b.\(STRING\).focus()/highlight("\1")/g'
highlight("STRING")`

Comment: Can you please add some explanation to your code? I totally can't get it.

Comment: Basicly, as all others say, expression between parentheses in the left side of the sed expression is recovered by using \# in the right side

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` version:

```
echo 'f.STRING.focus("Some data")' | awk '{gsub(/[[:alpha:]]\.[[:alpha:]]+\.focus\(/,"highlight(")}1'
highlight("Some data")
```

Using `sed`

```
echo 'b.STRING.focus("Some data")' | sed 's/[[:alpha:]]\.[[:alpha:]]*\.focus/highlight/g'
highlight("Some data")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's/f\.\([[:alnum:]]\+\).focus()/highlight("\1")/g' file.html
```

Here sed is finding

```
f.<string-with-1-and-more-alpha-numerics>.focus()
```

And capturing middle part into matching group #1

It is replacing that with:

```
highlight("\1")
```

Where '\1` is back-reference for matched group #1